# What does this mean? and how do I solve it? Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been building a signup form, using PDO. I'm new to PDO so I don't fully understand why I get that error. I checked my code, and it doesn't seem to be any syntax mistake. I don't know what it means when it says access violation.

I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]

This is my connect file

```
<?php 

//Our MySQL user account.
define('MYSQL_USER', 'root');

//Our MySQL password.
define('MYSQL_PASSWORD', '');

//The server that MySQL is located on.
define('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost');

//The name of our database.
define('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'private_beta_squire_app');

/**
 * PDO options / configuration details.
 * I'm going to set the error mode to "Exceptions".
 * I'm also going to turn off emulated prepared statements.
 */
$pdoOptions = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
);

/**
 * Connect to MySQL and instantiate the PDO object.
 */
$pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=" . MYSQL_HOST . ";dbname=" . MYSQL_DATABASE, //DSN
    MYSQL_USER, //Username
    MYSQL_PASSWORD, //Password
    $pdoOptions //Options
);

?>
```

And this is my form code

```
<?php

require 'password.php';

if ( isset ( $_POST ['submitButton'] ) ) {

    //if ( empty ( $_POST ['mail'] ) ) {
        //echo "Type your mail";
    //}

    //if ( empty ( $_POST ['password'] ) ) {
        //echo "Type your password";
    //}

    //if ( empty ( $_POST ['name'] ) ) {
        //echo "Type your name";
    //}

    //else {

        //Retrieve the field values from our registration form.
        $username = !empty ( $_POST ['mail'] ) ? trim ( $_POST ['mail'] ) : null;
        $pass = !empty ( $_POST ['password'] ) ? trim ( $_POST ['password'] ) : null;
        $name = !empty ( $_POST ['name'] ) ? trim ( $_POST ['name'] ) : null;
        $status = 'off';

        //TO ADD: Error checking (username characters, password length, etc).
        //Basically, you will need to add your own error checking BEFORE
        //the prepared statement is built and executed.

        //Now, we need to check if the supplied username already exists.

        //Construct the SQL statement and prepare it.
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT( email ) AS num FROM users WHERE email = :username";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare ( $sql );

        //Bind the provided username to our prepared statement.
        $stmt->bindValue ( ':username', $username );

        //Execute.
        $stmt->execute();

        //Fetch the row.
        $row = $stmt->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ;

        //If the provided username already exists - display error.
        //TO ADD - Your own method of handling this error. For example purposes,
        //I'm just going to kill the script completely, as error handling is outside
        //the scope of this tutorial.
        if ( $row ['num'] > 0 ) {

            die ( 'That email is already registered!' );

        }

        //Hash the password as we do NOT want to store our passwords in plain text.
        $passwordHash = password_hash ( $pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array ( "cost" => 12 ) );

        //Prepare our INSERT statement.
        //Remember: We are inserting a new row into our users table.
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, name, status, pass) VALUES (:username, :name, :status, :password;)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        //Bind our variables.
        $stmt->bindValue (':username', $username);
        $stmt->bindValue (':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindValue (':name', $status);
        $stmt->bindValue (':password', $passwordHash);      

        //Execute the statement and insert the new account.
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        //If the signup process is successful.
        if ( $result ) {

            //What you do here is up to you!
            header('location: index.php');

        }
    //}
}

?>
```

Comment: @chris85, Yeah buddy, I noticed it while scanning my code again. But now I get another error when trying to execute the last statement.

Comment: Now I get a `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031` on the line 71, which is the one that executes the statement

Comment: @chris85 You're the men. Thanks buddy, now it works. Can't believe it was such a dumb mistake. If you want, make your comment an answer, so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, name, status, pass) VALUES (:username, :name, :status, :password;)";
```

1. The `;` after the `password` placeholder closes the `insert` statement, which makes the query invalid.

```
$stmt->bindValue (':name', $name);
$stmt->bindValue (':name', $status);
```

2. Here you have used the same placeholder name twice, although your query used the correct name. If you used non-named placeholders this wouldn't have caused an issue.

So you should have:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, name, status, pass) VALUES (:username, :name, :status, :password)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

        //Bind our variables.
        $stmt->bindValue (':username', $username);
        $stmt->bindValue (':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindValue (':status', $status);
        $stmt->bindValue (':password', $passwordHash);      

        //Execute the statement and insert the new account.
        $result = $stmt->execute();
```

Alternative:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, name, status, pass) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        //Bind and execute the statement and insert the new account.
        $result = $stmt->execute(array($username, $name, $status, $passwordHash));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the interesting part. PDOException actually redefines $code as a String and not an Integer because for its case, $code actually contains the Exception's SQL State, which is composed of characters and numbers.

See this http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php

Comment: I don't have any variable called $code. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score -2):

From what I found while looking for this error code, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367445/uncaught-exception-pdoexception-with-message-sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or) SO post talks about a similar issue.

Try adding backticks to the columns and tables of your statements.

Comment: The tables/columns aren't reserved terms so backticks shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Oh wow, then I was just fast reading into the post. Didn't knew backticks were exclusively for reserved words.

Comment: You can use them in any instance, they aren't required though. It won't cause an error with the OPs current code. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks `are only necessary when the identifier is a MySQL reserved keyword, or when the identifier contains whitespace characters or characters beyond a limited set (see below)`